# Rockscroll or Metalscroll for Visual Studio 2010 (Minimap)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, plugins

Has any one found a replacement for [Rockscroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) or [Metalscroll](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a50c69b-9b35-4eb2-b06a-328758afcaa2) for Visual Studio 2010?

I miss it so much that I looked into making one my self but only have word highlighting working and a place holder scroll bar and seems to be much harder than I thought it would be. I'm happy to share what I got if someone is interested in helping.

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer. ProgressiveScroll is much closer to Rockscroll/Metalscroll than Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: ProgressiveScroll works great- the replacement for Rockscroll I was looking for.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) extension for VS2010 [just added](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/02/22/productivity-power-tools-introduces-find-organize-imports-for-vb-enhanced-scrollbar-middle-click-scrolling-and-more.aspx) an "Enhanced Scrollbar"![image: Enhanced Scrollbar Screenshot]

To enable the minimap go to `Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools->Enhanced Scroll Bar` and check "Full map mode". Optionally you can assign the background color and highlighted region.

Comment: Just curious about the "pedigree" of this one--I know that MetalScroll came after RockScroll, which, unlike the former, was born at Microsoft. Does this extension take after MetalScroll in code and/or in spirit? It's hard to tell, I suppose. In any case, nifty tool!

Comment: I find this one hard to use for long source files (when it is most needed) -- it only renders every nth line, making it not correspond particularly well to the actual file.

Comment: I find it hard to use as well. The main problem for me is that it highlights the word the cursor is on immediately, and not on doubleclick, as metalscroll does. This leads to a lot of flickering when you move your cursor across the file, plus you cannot move your cursor/edit while still seeing originally highlighted items.

Comment: the fact that it hides lines makes it highly annoying

Comment: It will highlight the search results on the scroll bar which kind of does the same thing as the metalscroll double click, although is more clumsy.

Comment: Productivity Power Tools has two separate mechanisms for highlighting all occurrances. (1) it highlights whatever the cursor is on instantly, (2) it highlights the search term in Ctrl+F. If you don't like mechanism #1 because it does not work by double-click, as a substitute you can (i) disable mechanism #1 in the Options dialog and (ii) double-click a word and press Ctrl+F. Not as convenient as MetalScroll, but not bad either.

Answer (score 14):

Just tried [ProgressiveScroll](http://code.google.com/p/progressive-scroll/) and it looks and feels like the original MetalScroll; it also works in Visual Studio 2012!

Comment: The version I just tried and it didn't work quite well for me

Comment: It is awesome! Captures the useful part of Metalscroll/Rockscroll and disposes of all the unneeded clutter. Seems stable and solid. Everything required is configurable. I can now disable useless and slow "highlight references to symbol under cursor". Visual Studio team - take note.

Answer (score 7):

A user named Kryo at the "Sins of solar empire" forum have made a pretty good imitation of MetalScrollbar for VS 2010, called [MetalMargin](http://forums.sinsofasolarempire.com/412418). Available [here](http://files.kryofx.com/MetalMargin.vsix%20%22here%22.). Just installed it, and it seems to work pretty well, although highlight on double click is not yet implemented.

Comment: It is very good, but needs some more work. I think it has a potential to be the closest in terms of functionality to MetalScroll/RockScroll.

Comment: I've just discovered ProgressiveScroll. Ticks all boxes for me when it comes to Metalscroll/Rockscroll-type functionality.

Answer (score 3):

David Pugh released a version of his [Structure Margin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fe432eb5-c538-47a9-9919-fba1a8f5b261), which serves a similar purpose.  His [All Margins](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/465a0d53-5133-4edd-a0cd-94484fe3d853) extension combines a bunch of the other smaller extensions in the same vein.

It's not exactly the same, but I find the structure margin to be an interesting way to visualize the entire code file.

Comment: That link is now dead. It seems it's all folded into productivity power tools, which is a pain because I'm looking for the double-click-highlight-all-instances feature.

Comment: Seconded. Double click to highlight instances is a must.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it myself yet but [AllMargins](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/43bc4a3a-0182-4c36-8159-a0a4cdfd04bd) looks [really nice](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/465a0d53-5133-4edd-a0cd-94484fe3d853/showImage/18175). Whoops you already linked it Noah Richards. Sorry.

Comment: I prefer this one over the one included in the power tools.

Answer (score 1):

The code is also available for the [OverviewMargin](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OverviewMargin) - I haven't tried it at all, but it may be a [good place to start](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditorprerelease/thread/2ec742ec-e91c-4b13-8aa1-78dd9a784bc6) from if you want to roll your own.

Comment: @Lodle, oh, cool! Sorry 'bout that. I've just installed StructureMargin, it's ok, but what I really miss is being able to see all instances of the highlighted text in the margin... I'll have a look-see.

Comment: @Lodle, think I'll ask a question here to see if anyone has managed to make it build. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688825/has-anyone-got-overviewmargin-to-compile-with-vs2010-rtm)

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what i miss. :(

Answer (score 1):

Did You try RockMargin ?
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1b0d7360-40dd-447e-8bef-90e2cf52f683
This is useful

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a replacement for just the Highlighting part of RockScroll, the free plugin ["Highlight all occurrences of selected word"](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb) does exactly that.

[image]