# Has anyone got OverviewMargin to compile with VS2010 RTM?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

As I am severely addicted to [rockscroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx), I'm looking for an [replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672277/rockscroll-or-metalscroll-for-vis-2010) for VS2010, I tried downloading [OverviewMargin](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OverviewMargin/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3957), and it works, but I wanted to have a look at the code to see if I could adapt it to behave more like rockscroll, but I can't get it to compile.

Has anyone managed to get it to compile with the latest version for VS2010?

(For what it's worth, I've solved part of my original problems, the colours of the caret markers can be changed in the registry: \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Text Editor)

**Some of the errors**

- SettingsStoreImpl.cs, line 20: SVsServiceProvider doe snot exist in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.
- OverviewMargin.cs, line 645: ScrollMapWrapper does not implement IScrollMap.CoordinateBufferEnd *(weird one this, because it's internal code)*
- StructureAdornmentManager.cs, line 112: ITagAggregator<BlockTagger.IBlockTag> does not contain a definition for BatchedTagsChanged.
- MarkersToMarks.cs, line 35: Type or namespace IVsVisibleTextMarkerTag could not be found
- ErrorMarks.cs, line 36: Type or namespace IErrorTag could not be found
- StructureMarginFactory.cs, line 17: Duplicate 'Order' attribute
- OverviewMargin.cs, line 190: DefaultTextViewOptions does not contain definition for 'IsViewportLeftClippedId'
- OverviewMargin.cs, line 200: IWpfTextView does not contain definition for 'LineHeight'.
- OverviewMargin.cs, line 623: IScrollMap does not contain a definition for 'End'.
- OverviewMargin.cs, line 695: IScrollMap does not contain a definition for 'Start'.
- OverviewMargin.cs, line 700: IScrollMap does not contain a definition for 'End'

Comment: What are the compilation errors you are getting?

Comment: @Noah Richards, not at the office now, so I've just added the one I remember, I'll add more tomorrow.

Comment: It's probably missing assembly references due to a mismatch in 64/32 bit OS.  Can you check the project file to see if it is referencing, say, "Program Files (x86)", and you are on a 32-bit OS, or vice versa (referencing "Program Files", but needs the (x86))?

Comment: I think its missing files from the source code as one of the projects fails to load.

Comment: @Lodle, you have to install the VS2010 SDK, that resolves the projects loading problem.

Comment: @Noah, I'm not sure what you mean, I see no references to Program Files in the project file. If I look at the Configuration Manager, all the projects are set to Any CPU, except RepackVsix which is set to x86. The second error in the list above makes me wonder if there isn't some incoherence in the code I downloaded...

Comment: @Benjol hmmm i have installed the sdk. Might need to add references in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Enhanced Scrollbar" that was [just added](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/02/22/productivity-power-tools-introduces-find-organize-imports-for-vb-enhanced-scrollbar-middle-click-scrolling-and-more.aspx) to [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) for VS2010![image: Enhanced Scrollbar Screenshot]

Comment: interesting, I'll have a look.