# Visual Studio 2010 Minimap - What happened to it and is there a plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 was projected to have a minimap feature for scrolling through code files.

What is a minimap? A skinny map on the left side where you can click to get to different parts of the file.

http://www.sublimetext.com/

There were screen shots of this being implemented in Visual Studio 2010, but it would appear that the feature did not ship with the product.

Is there a plugin available for VS2010 that has this?

Thanks

Comment: I know it's a crappy answer, but I'd be glad to help out if you have any questions in trying to port metalscroll over.  The author has already said he isn't interested (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3a50c69b-9b35-4eb2-b06a-328758afcaa2), but I'm always glad to offer help to anyone that is.  Also, if you want to try to write this feature from scratch, I can help with that too :)

Comment: Thanks. I may be interested in a few months

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rockscroll or Metalscroll for Visual Studio 2010 (Minimap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672277/rockscroll-or-metalscroll-for-visual-studio-2010-minimap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RockScroll-like document map feature was [apparently dropped](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditorprerelease/thread/2ec742ec-e91c-4b13-8aa1-78dd9a784bc6) from the VS2010 release.

I've been giving the [AllMargins](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/465a0d53-5133-4edd-a0cd-94484fe3d853) extension a go, and so far I'm liking it.  I'd love to see a full port of RockScroll/MetalScroll to VS2010 though.

Comment: We can always fall back on regions to pseudo-accomplish this, but as a starcraft player I really would like a minimap!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's something there.  I see a colored bar next to my code, usually green, between the left rail that you can click to set breakpoints and the vertical line with +/- nodes to allow collapsing regions.  From 10,000 feet I suppose it could resemble a "minimap".  Haven't figured out what exactly it means yet though.  Maybe I haven't zoomed small enough yet.

See it?

Comment: Hans, I see it, but sometimes it's yellow and sometimes it's green. I think that reflects whether the code is new or has been saved... helps one keep track of changes that have either not been saved or possibly committed to source control. I could be completely wrong.

Comment: That sounds good, I do see yellow when I type.  I didn't know I needed it.  Ever saw another color?