# Using RockScroll v1 with Visual Studio 2010 problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I knew about RockScroll at this [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx), I downloaded it to run on Visual Studio 2010, but it doesn't seem to work with VS 2010.

What might be the problem? Doesn't RockScroll v1 work with VS 2010?

- If so, what would be an alternative?
- If not, what might be wrong?

Comment: Isn't there already a built-in Rockscroll (symbol highlighting) built-in VS2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RockScroll doesn't work with VS2010.  Last I checked, there were a couple of somewhat-similar-looking extensions on the VS Gallery, though I don't know if any work with VS2010 and the new editor.  I know at MS a couple of VS folks are working on a new RockScroll-like VSIX in their free time, for possible inclusion in a future version of the Pro Power Tools, though I haven't heard anything about it in the last couple months.

Answer (score 7):

The **[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)** now include a scroll bar similar to RockScroll/MetalScroll as described by [@shaunmartin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24245/shaunmartin) in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672277/rockscroll-or-metalscroll-for-vis-2010):

[image]

Comment: While a great set of tools, they fall short of MetalScroll functionality in scrollbar department. The main problem is that it highlights references immediately, not on doubleclick. This makes it useless for me. Actually it makes me seasick from all the flickering it causes when you move around the file :-)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatives are [MetalScroll](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3a50c69b-9b35-4eb2-b06a-328758afcaa2) and [AllMargins](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/465a0d53-5133-4edd-a0cd-94484fe3d853).

I haven't tried MetalScroll.  I installed AllMargins, and it's neat, but I can't say its been very useful.