# No more red dot on scroll bar in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

At Visual Studio 2010, there will be a red dot(s) on scroll bar indicated where your code has errors. Also a other color dots for other message etc.

But after installed Visual Studio 2012, I cannot see this feature anywhere, tried toolbar-options, nowhere to found.

Am I miss something? Or Microsoft just removed this feature.

**{EDIT}**

Sample of Visual Studio 2010
[image]

And Visual Studio 2012, where these nice little dot candy go?
[image]

Comment: The dots on the scroll bar are not part of VS. You must have a 3rd party plugin (I also thing the red dot on the tab is not VS either). It's not resharper thats doing it either, reshaper makes it look a lot prettier! (see here: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/reviewers_guide.html)

Comment: I have to start a bounty after two days and ask who knows whats that, Now I have no clue where I get it, and I cannot find any folder/file hints that too :( I have to say, the feature is very useful.

Comment: This thread may help you, it discusses many alternatives. I don't know if they have 2012 compatibility yet however. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672277/rockscroll-or-metalscroll-for-visual-studio-2010-minimap

Comment: Thanks. Now I think I might installed the Productivity Power Tools http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef BUt it does not have a VS2012 version :(

Comment: I've just found (but not tried) [this](http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/tag/vs2012/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you got code errors? :P

Check the editor settings out, I am pretty sure it is there it might just be off by default.

> As you add code and build your solution, you may see different-colored wavy underlines (known as squiggles) appearing in your code. These marks notify you of problems Visual Studio has detected in your code. For example, red squiggles denote syntax errors, blue squiggles denote compiler errors, green squiggles denote warnings, and purple squiggles denote other types of error. For example, they are used for "rude" edits in Visual Basic, which are changes that are made during Edit and Continue and that will result in compiler errors.

You can see the default color for each error and warning squiggle in the Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts and Colors dialog box. Look for Syntax Error, Compiler Error, Warning, and Other Error.

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efc4xwkb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have squiggle in the editor itself, I mean the colors in scrollbar for the editor is gone

Comment: I upload two pictures, could you please check if your VS 2010 has these features.

Comment: I think you are using a plugin, because mine doesn't have that feature.

Comment: :( I do not remember what I installed over the years. And now I am addicting to these little candies, God help me

Comment: Yep ha ha I have the same file, maybe you can resurrect them by checking out settings folders in My Documents Folder??

Comment: What has this answer got to do with the question?

Answer (score 16):

The dots you see on the scrollbar are definitely a feature of the "Productivity Power Tools" Extensions "Enhanced Scrollbar".

[Link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

There are 3 Modes to enhance the Scrollbar, your Screenshot displays the first (default) one.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no equivalent for VS2012. Or does anyone know of an extension that improves the scrollbar like that?

Comment: Productivity Power Tools for VS 2012 is now released. See [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you were using the jetbrains resharper tool? That provides the feature you describe, but I don't recall ever seeing it in visual studio

Comment: no, just plain old original Visual Studio 2012 Install download from microsoft

Comment: To make sure I do not have anything installed over the years, I double checked and no jetbrains anywhere in my disk. I upload two pictures, could you please check if your VS 2010 has these features.